# Toggling RxJava Subscription w/ a Button

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I've been trying to toggle the subscription to 2 Observables that I `merge()` using a single button in Android and a `boolean mSubsciptionToggle`. The toggle is set to `false` when the fragment is first created.

I'm creating the Observables myself using `Observable.create()`, which looks something like this:

```
    Observable<String> observable = Observable.create(observer -> {

        final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Log incoming broadcasts
            }
        };

        getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        if (mSubscriptionToggle) {
            observer.onComplete();
        }
    });
```

I then add an `OnClickListener` to my button like so:

```
    mStickyButton.setOnClickListener( (View view) -> {

                // Observables were created from the first code snippet
                Observable.merge(mBatteryObservable, mAirplaneModeObservable)
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(// Logging each emitted String);

                // Toggling the subscription each time the button is clicked
                mSubscriptionToggle = !mSubscriptionToggle;
            }
    );
```

My problem is: when the button is clicked the first time, `onComplete()` immediately happens. However, I called `subscribe()` before this happens:

`mSubscriptionToggle = !mSubscriptionToggle`

Why is my boolean changing after I call `subscribe()`?

Comment: i think in this code all happen synchronously. You observe on main thread and subscribe on main thread. If you want to change boolean before subscribe, try to do this above merging

Comment: That could be a quick and easy fix and does work when I try it. I've added some extra log statements to see why the code in my original question wasn't working as expected. My guess is that `merge()` must create the observables in another scope or thread, which causes a delay. Not absolutely sure though.

Comment: You schedule the subscription on the main thread after the click handler has run, thus the mSubscriptionToggle has been set to true. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish, but I'd have a Disposable field. If it is null, I'd create the sequence upon the button click. If it is not null, I'd dispose it and set it back to null. In the create then, I'd implement a proper deregistering action via setCancellable.